# Best way to trace possible root cause of card fraud?

Tags: united-kingdom, fraud, debit-card

I recently had a fraudulent transaction on my debit card (in the UK, where I am based).  Having blocked the card, my main concern is to determine how much information has been stolen and how?

As this was an online transaction, the fraudster may have needed only superficial information regarding my card to complete the transaction e.g., expiry date, long card number and security code. These details could, theoretically, have been stolen while I used my card in person (at an ATM or while paying for goods) or they could have been stolen via hacking or phishing of myself or someone who has my details, which I would view as a lot more nefarious.

When I reported the transaction to my bank, I didn’t ask whether other auxiliary details were used in the transaction e.g.  my DoB, telephone number, security questions which may have been indicative of a wider problem.

I have no reason to believe that I am personally the victim of a hack or phishing. I use anti-virus and am careful with online transactions.
My questions are:

(1) Is it normal for banks to be able to give more information about a specific fraudulent transaction to their customers to help them understand how much information has been compromised?

(2) What is the best way to approach finding how much information may have been stolen and how?

Answer (score 3):

You're asking a question which likely will never be answered.  The bank will probably never disclose details about the transaction(s) - here in the U.S. they are under no such obligation. And I doubt it's much different in the U.K.  The only recourse would be to ask which online merchant the card was used at, which let's you figure out what info they collect when processing a transaction.  Unfortunately a majority of online merchants only require card number, expiry date and security code, so that's probably true here as well.
There is no way to know what info was obtained about you either, so that's going to be a dead end.
The only thing you can do at this point is keep a close eye on your credit file for any odd activity, lock it if you can to keep anyone from changing info (with enough info from a victim sometimes thieves will impersonate the victim to change personal info in the credit file to redirect mail and so on) or trying to open new accounts, and check with other creditors to make them aware you're a victim so they can note your file and keep an eye out as well.

Comment: Yes, the bank won't want to risk violating privacy laws. Criminals still have rights.

Comment: @mattman944, yeah it sucks that the criminals seem to have more rights than their victims...